# Floating element without displaying inline

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj2f9ccf/), with 3 floating elements. I need the "float" elements to display on top of the other, not side by side although they're floating.

HTML structure:

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.main, .float {
  border: 1px solid;
  float: right;
  height: 50vh;
}

.main {
  width: 70%;
}

.float {
  width: 30%; // It won't break if it has 15%
}
```

EDITED:

Forgot to mention that I can't nest the "float" elements in a 30% width div in my current layout scheme.

Comment: I have a hard time visualising what you want. Do you want all the divs to display side by side, even if together they're wider than the window?

Comment: As in the Fiddle, they're already side by side. I need them not to display side by side even though they're floating.

Comment: So how should they appear..? Like this- ? - https://jsfiddle.net/kj2f9ccf/2/

Comment: On top of the other. So that way they will fit the 30% left space.

Comment: @TWFPSP So... like this? https://jsfiddle.net/L21vgsLy/

Comment: What about `* {box-sizing: border-box;}`?

Comment: Yes, like this! Input your answer and I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do but, from the comments...

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
.main,
.float {
  border: 1px solid;
  float: right;
}
.main {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50vh;
}
.float {
  width: 30%;
  height: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Main</div>
<div class="float">Float 1</div>
<div class="float">Float 2</div>
```